# Как обработать данные value в GridView?

Tags: yii2

Есть цикл, который формирует колонки для GridView:

```
$columns = [];
        foreach ($this->paramLabels() as $id => $label) {
            $columns[] = [
                'attribute' => "paramValues[{$id}]",
                'filter' => Html::activeTextInput($this, "paramValues[{$id}]",['class' => 'form-control']),
                'label' => $label,
                'contentOptions'=>['data-param'=>"{$id}"],
                'value' => "paramValues.{$id}.value",
            ];
        }
```

Далее:

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $columns,
            ]);
```

не понимаю как мне обработать 'value' функцией так, чтобы значение value было обернуто в теги например `<div class="">...</div>`, то есть не понятно как составить саму функцию, что и как в нее передавать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается с помощью анонимных функций
Для примера:

```
[
      'attribute'=>'category_image',
        'contentOptions' =>['class' => 'table_class','style'=>'display:block;'],
        'content'=>function($data){
            return "value";
        }
]
```

В функцию передается объект dataProvider'а и в ней вы можете делать с ним все что захотите, обвернуть в div и т.д.